# Tachanun on 'erev Yom Ha'Atzmaut'

Tags: tefilla, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer, yom-haatzmaut

For those that hold Yom Ha'Atzmaut to be a 'chag' or 'pseudo-chag' (to whatever extent, [see here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/is-yom-haatzmaut-a-chag)), does it directly follow that tachanun is not said at mincha on erev Yom Ha'Atzmaut?

Comment: dupeable? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7991/759

Comment: http://www.ravaviner.com/2009/04/customs-laws-of-yom-ha-atzmaut.html http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-n_5k2FWTWwI/T5fFxFvg2EI/AAAAAAAAEok/0Ch9gBZ2AoE/s1600/Yom+Yerushalayim+2.jpg

Answer (score 6):

[Collected from the writings of Ha-Rav Aviner]

1. Tachanun on Erev Yom Ha-Atzmaut
   It is proper to recite Tachanun at Minchah of Erev Yom Ha-Atzamaut, as the Chief Rabbinate of Israel has decreed this day "Remembrance Day for the Fallen Soldiers of Tzahal," which is a day of mourning.[1]

[1]Iturei Cohanim #97, Shut She'eilat Shlomo 3:147, Sichot Ha-Rav Tzvi Yehudah: Medinat Yisrael #34 p. 7, Sichot Ha-Rav Tzvi Yehudah: Yom Ha-Atzamaut ve-Yom Yerushalayim p. 73, Sichot Ha-Rav Tzvi Yehudah: Eretz Yisrael pp. 264-265

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Raf. Thanks for the contribution. Consider taking the following short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the site.

Answer (score 3):

The Koren Yom Haatzmaut Machzor says to say tachanun at mincha of erev yom haatzmaut if you daven during mincha gedola, but that one skips tachanun during mincha ketana.

Comment: Where does that come from?  I don't think I've ever heard that with respect to any other day.

Comment: I can only suggest an explanation for this now that I lived for a number of years in Israel. The day before Yom Haatzmaut is Yom Hazikaron, remembrance for the fallen soldiers of Israel. As such it is a very somber day with lots of memorial ceremonies, El Malei Rachamim in the morning tefila and deserves Tachanun. As the evening arrives, the joy of Yom Haatzmaut comes in and it wouldn't be appropriate to say Tachanun at such a time

Answer (score 3):

R Eliezer Melamed in Peninei Halacha ([Tefila 21:7](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-21-07/)) writes we do not say Tachanun on Erev Yom Haatzmaut

> Today, ever since Hashem began to bring forth our redemption, Tachanun
>   is not recited on Yom HaAtzma’ut (Israel’s Independence Day), and on
>   the 28th of Iyar, Yom Yerushalayim (Jerusalem Liberation Day), **nor at
>   Minchah before each of them**

This is also the opinion of the Chief Rabinate of Israel (quoted [here](https://matzav.com/chief-rabbinate-on-tachanun-on-yom-haatzmaut/) from 2012)

> ... the Rabbanut explains that, in their opinion, **Tachanun should not be
>   said today at Mincha of Yom HaZikaron, Thursday being Yom HaAtzmaut**,
>   and on Friday 5 Iyar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My congregation did not say tachanun at mincha today. This is seemingly based on the fact that the Rinat Yisrael siddur does not list it as one of the exceptions to the tachanun at mincha before a chag rule.

Comment: How does your evidence support your claim? (Incidentally, your claim seems inaccurate given the somber nature of Yom HaZikkaron.)

Comment: This is not a given, just because Yom Ha'Atzma'ut is a "chag". Erev Yom Kippur can also be considered a "chag", in some fashion, and is of far older origin than Yom Ha'atzma'ut. Yet, on the mincha before it, Tachanun is said, IIRC. Erev Rosh Hashanah also has the same rules, yet, ERH, itself is not a chag.

Comment: @DanF Compare with Pesach Sheni.  Since the celebration only began late on the 14th Iyar there was no celebration on the preceding night and, therefore, no skipping of tachanun on the afternoon of the 13th

Comment: The fact that your shul didn't say tachanun doesn't mean that it follows automatically. When I was in yeshiva, we did say tachanun at mincha on erev yom ha'atzmaut.

Comment: @Daniel, what type of yeshiva did you go to though?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt A yeshiva that _did not_ say _tachanun_ on the day of _Yom Ha'atzmaut_.

Answer (score -3):

It depends really if the night is also a chag. If it is only the day then tachnun is said.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, cham. Do you have a source for this idea? Also, do you know of anyone who holds that the day is a chag while the night isn't?

Comment: Why would it only be the daytime?